# Convert flat PHP array to multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following array structure:

```
[parents] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [created] => 2014-11-09 13:47:37
                [content] => This is a test discussion
                [status] => 1
                [parent] => 0
                [project_id] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 4
                [user_id] => 1
                [created] => 2014-11-09 13:52:02
                [content] => 456789
                [status] => 1
                [parent] => 0
                [project_id] => 1
            )

    )

[children] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 2
                [user_id] => 1
                [created] => 2014-11-09 13:47:53
                [content] => This is a test reply....
                [status] => 1
                [parent] => 1
                [project_id] => 1
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 3
                [user_id] => 1
                [created] => 2014-11-09 13:48:13
                [content] => This is a test reply....!!!
                [status] => 1
                [parent] => 1
                [project_id] => 1
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [id] => 5
                [user_id] => 1
                [created] => 2014-11-09 13:52:17
                [content] => 8765432
                [status] => 1
                [parent] => 4
                [project_id] => 1
            )

    )
```

I would like to merge them into a parent/child relationship so it looks like follows:

```
[parents] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 1
                [user_id] => 1
                [created] => 2014-11-09 13:47:37
                [content] => This is a test discussion
                [status] => 1
                [parent] => 0
                [project_id] => 1
                [children] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 2
                                [user_id] => 1
                                [created] => 2014-11-09 13:47:53
                                [content] => This is a test reply....
                                [status] => 1
                                [parent] => 1
                                [project_id] => 1
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [id] => 3
                                [user_id] => 1
                                [created] => 2014-11-09 13:48:13
                                [content] => This is a test reply....!!!
                                [status] => 1
                                [parent] => 1
                                [project_id] => 1
                            )
                        )
            )
     )
```

How could I go about doing that with PHP?

Comment: Did you googled `array_merge` ?

Comment: By iterating the children array and appending the results to the appropriate parent element - what have you tried so far?

Comment: I attempted to write something like that, but I got stuck when figuring how to add the child array to the parent array.  Since I need to add it based on the parents id not the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that all `id`s are unique in your `parents` array, you can do this:

```
// build a new array using parent's ID values as the key, 
// to simplify searching for parent IDs. 
foreach ($parents as $key => $value){
    $merged[$value['id']] = $value;
}

foreach ($children as $child){
    $parentID = $child['parent'];
    if (array_key_exists( $parentID, $merged )) {
        // add the child array to its parent's ['children'] value
        $merged[$parentID]['children'][] = $child;
    }
}
```

In the resulting array `$merged`, the key of each parent item will be set to its `id`, and all children will be nested under their corresponding parents.